# Copying Arrays and making them longer?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, arraylist

I need to write a method called copyRange that takes as parameters two arrays a1 and a2, two starting indexes i1 and i2, and a length l, and copies the first l elements of a1 starting at index i1 into array a2 starting at index i2.

For example, given these two arrays:

```
int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] a2 = {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26};
copyRange(a1, a2, 0, 3, 2);
```

After the preceding call, the contents of a2 would be {21, 22, 23, 1, 2, 26}. You may assume that the parameters' values are valid, that the arrays are large enough to hold the data, and so on.

I'm very confused on how to start this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask here how to do your home work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java library [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), exactly for this.

You can use it like this:

```
int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int arr2[] = {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26};
System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr2, 3, 2); 
//copies 2 items from arr1, starting_index 0 to arr2, starting_index 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by defining your method signature for 
`copyRange(a1, a2, 0, 3, 2);`

you know it returns an array of ints and its parameters so, write that

```
public ??? copyRange(int a1[],...) {

}
```

Remember that arrays are past as references in Java, so you must not change the values in a1 and a2. Instead you should make a copy of a2, then insert the elements from a1 and return the copy.

[System.arraycopy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm) is a built-in method for coping arrays in Java, and its super fast. You can probably make good use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken arguments same above the question.
copyRange(a1, a2, 0, 3, 2)

You can get any two arrays(a1 ,a2).

0 is "i1", the starting index of a1 array.

3 is "i2", the starting index of a2 array.

2 is "l", the number of elements from a1.

At the end 2 elements from a1 array, starting from index 0, in other terms the first two elements of a1 array, will replace index 3 and index 4, in other terms 4th and 5th elements of the a2 array.

```
class First {

  public static void copyRange(int a1[], int a2[], int ind1, int ind2, int len) {

    for (int i = ind1; i < len + ind1; i++) {
      a2[ind2 + (i - ind1)] = a1[i];

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int a2[] = {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26};
    copyRange(a1, a2, 0, 3, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Tharaka, welcome to Stack Overflow. When you add an answer with a code, you might want to add an explanation how it works, and how it solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly where the source of this problem is because I just solved it online as well (6 years later...)

Anyways, for those who might still need help, this is one way to do this.

```
public static void copyRange(int[] a1, int[] a2, int i1, int i2, int length) {
    for (int i = i2; i < i2 + length; i++) {
        a2[i] = a1[i1];
        i1++;
    }
}
```

No need to use libraries as the original question does not intend the student to use any additional libraries or methods or functions.

This solution loops the second passed array `a2` from the index `i2` up to the `length`. While doing so, it takes the value from `a1` from its starting index `i1` and updates `a2` accordingly. Then `i1` is incremented along with the for loop.